# How to pass my API key in correctly with Angular 14 and SwaggerUI ASp.netCore 6 Web API

Tags: .net, angular, api, asp.net-core

This is a silly question but I dont know how to check to see, Im unsure how to pass my API key when making calls to the API I made in .Net 6 CWA

Im currently hosting the Web API on [Heroku](https://chuckwarsapi.herokuapp.com/swagger/index.html):

The Curl According to the UI looks like this:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://chuckwarsapi.herokuapp.com/search?Query=luke' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'ApiKey: xxxxx'
```

I Am calling the API like this in my Component:

```
return this.httpClient.get(`https://chuckwarsapi.herokuapp.com/search?Query=${query}&ApiKey=${this.API_KEY}`);
```

I have built a Interceptor on my SPA but that hasnt helped as I still get

```
error
: 
"Api Key was not provided"
```

The Way I added the API Key on the .Net was through some MiddleWare that checks to see if the API key is present

The middleware code:

```
 private const string APIKEYNAME = "ApiKey";
        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(APIKEYNAME, out var extractedApiKey))
            {
                context.Result = new ContentResult()
                {
                    StatusCode = 401,
                    Content = "Api Key was not provided"
                };
                return;
            }

            var appSettings = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

            var apiKey = appSettings.GetValue<string>(APIKEYNAME);

            if (!apiKey.Equals(extractedApiKey))
            {
                context.Result = new ContentResult()
                {
                    StatusCode = 401,
                    Content = "Api Key is not valid"
                };
                return;
            }

            await next();
        }
```

I understand that the Api Key has to be referred to as **ApiKey** But im unsure how to pass it in the url. or how els to approach giving it the api key when I make the calls

here the Interceptor Code:

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `ApiKey xxxxx`
      }
    });

    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

The Interceptor is being called in my module as such:

```
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ApiInterceptorService, multi: true },
  ],
```

Appsettings.json in .net side:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApiKey": "xxxxx"
}
```

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `ApiKey` header in the request, instead of  `Authorization` header

```
request = request.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    ApiKey: `xxxxx`
  }
});
```

Comment: That seems to be the case, I would just ask if you could elaborate a bit.

Is this caused by me and the way the middleware is setup? is there Specific that need to be followed to set the API in the Authentication(which im assuming should be for OAuth Tokens and such) or does it not matter at all?

Comment: Yes, in addition to ApiKey, you had to generate a token for the user. And you had to pass that token as a part of `Authorization` header. [Handling Authentication in Angular](https://medium.com/deskera-engineering/handle-authentication-in-angular-8e18b7f55f2c)

Comment: So its typical for API keys to be in the Header Not in the Authentication bit of the header?

Comment: In my experience, I haven't seen `ApiKey` as a part of `Authorization` header.